# Automating file downloads using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For a corporate website which hosts a bunch of documents, I am writing a JavaScript to download each of these documents in an automated way.

The approach I am following is having a html file created with these links and a javascript in the page that will iterate through the links and simulate a click.

Unfortunately, the "clicks" happen only for the first link but stops after the further.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].click();
}
```

```html
<a href="path1">file 1</a>
<a href="path2">file 2</a>
<a href="path3">file 3</a>
<a href="path4">file 4</a>
```

Comment: You'll need to wait until the first click's request completes, I suspect.

Comment: Is there a reason for using browser JS for this instead of node? Saving batches of files from links on a page will be much more efficient and pleasant outside of the browser.

Comment: No particular reason other than lack of sophisticated tools. What's node? I have access to Excel VBA, Notepad at my disposal

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing about wait the first click to finish...

Your idea is almost there... but you forget an attribute `download`:

```
HTML: 
<a download href="http://internal.corporateurl.com/filepath/file.pdf">Link 1</a>

JS:
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
links.forEach(anchor => anchor.click())
```

Just one importante thing: your client should be allowed to download these files from the server. You cannot just put whichever pdf file you find on the internet.

---

EDIT:

Just to illustrate my last sentence, here's an example:

This link refers to a PDF outside my domain. So instead of downloading, its opening on the screen:

```
<a href="https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/gchen/www/download/java/LearnJava.pdf" download>link</a>
```

This is a relative path pointing to my project, so it works properly.

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>link</a>
```

Reference for you to try: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Cheers,

Comment: I didn't understand your last note, could you rephrase or clarify please? I'll definitely try your solution

Comment: The files you want to download should be hosted under the same domain your site is. In case not, I suspect you'll need to do some extra configuration to allow it on the server that hosts the files.

Comment: Do you have any better resource than w3schools?

Comment: What do you mean by a "better resource"? Don't you trust them?